# Update variable by button and by custom event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to update a variable, for example counter, from buttons and from WebSockets.
How to do it in react? Currently I use "useEffect" hook, but I don't think it's a correct way,
because I'd like to avoid `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` on every counter change.
Does anyone know a solution?

my code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [log, setLog] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onCustomEvent = function(){
      setCount(count+1)
    }
    logEvent('addEventListener')
    document.addEventListener('custom-event', onCustomEvent)

    return () => {
      logEvent('removeEventListener')
      document.removeEventListener('custom-event', onCustomEvent)
    }
  }, [count, setCount])

  function dispatchEvent(){
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('custom-event'))
  }

  function logEvent(msg){
    console.log(msg)
    setLog([...log, msg])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Increase counter
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatchEvent()}>
        Dispatch a Custom Event, for example from a WebSockets
      </button>
      <div>I need to update a variable, for example counter, from buttons and from WebSockets.
         How to do it in react? Currently I use "useEffect" hook, but I don't think it's a correct way, 
         because I'd like to avoid addEventListener and removeEventListener on every counter change.
        Does anyone know a solution?</div>
      <div>count value is {count}</div>
      <div>Log (see console also):</div>
      {log.map((msg, i) => <div key={i}>{msg}</div>)}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

See https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mardraze/use-effect-problem/main
And github https://github.com/mardraze/use-effect-problem

Comment: What is not working in the code you provided?

Comment: I'd like to avoid addEventListener and removeEventListener on every counter change

Comment: make the `onCustomEvent` to use the callback format of the `setCount` so you do not have to update it again. `setCount( prevCount => prevCount + 1 );` See https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mardraze/use-effect-problem/csb-8mk7fw/draft/exciting-firefly

Comment: I think you're stuck assigning event listeners that way (it is in fact common).    To add on to @GabrielePetrioli, if you write your `setCount` that way you should also remove the `count` in the dependency array.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thanks for your reply, but I have a problem with access to your code

Comment: @possum Ok, so how to store shared counter value?

Comment: @user1120241 It still gets stored in the state as is.  See the answer below.  You can just update your `useEffect` to what's provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you can remove the dependency on `count` by changing the `setCount` argument to a function that updates the old value.  You can then leave the dependency array empty.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onCustomEvent = function () {
      setCount((oldCount) => oldCount + 1);
    };
    logEvent("addEventListener");
    document.addEventListener("custom-event", onCustomEvent);

    return () => {
      logEvent("removeEventListener");
      document.removeEventListener("custom-event", onCustomEvent);
    };
  }, []);
```

I checked this in your codepen and it works with the single `addEventListener` invocation and keeps the state working.

Comment: Thanks. I've created new code to provide the solution. https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mardraze/use-effect-problem/solutions